# vba filter and paste as values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter and copy the values from one sheet to another but I get stuck in one of my codes.  I can't seem to paste as values or don't know the correct syntax.

```
     Set ws1 = Worksheets("AT")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("BT")
   lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With ws1.Range("B2", "R" & lr1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        .Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(lr2, "A")
        .PasteSpecial (XlPastevalues, , , )
    End With
```

The rest of the codes follow through without .pastespecial line so that is why I am not copying everything here except the portion I have issues with. Right now I don't have the following format because I am pasting values on the existing data at the end so I am just adding data (more rows) to it. And there are formats on the existing so that is why I don't want to mess with it.

```
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Also if anyone can also suggest a different way to do filters let me know. My current codes only work if my range is a table, so if I don't create a table for it, it will fail. My data is from A1 to R and there is a header. Without setting it as a table, it will filter from B2 and it will have wrong filter. See below. When I filter and copy, I do not need to copy header to my existing data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways of doing it but without changing you existing code much you can just split the copy paste methods. Unless you are talking big data sets it shouldn't be a problem.

```
Set ws1 = Worksheets("AT")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BT")
lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
With ws1.Range("B2", "R" & lr1)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    .Copy
End With
ws2.Cells(lr2, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! Is there a way to do filter without assigning the range as a table? As i have described it in my second half of my issue? your codes works fine but I need to set my data range as a table.

Comment: sure is, just use the .ListObjects("Table1") reference in pretty much the same way. If you record a macro it will give you the exact syntax. Probably easier than trying to get it by hand. Just take the bit you need from it but it is close to the same. I like to do an initial clear of all filters and then filter on what I want to see. When you do your copy method on the table (this is from memory so not 100% sure) use the .DataBodyRange and you might need to expressly state visible cells only but I don't remember at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, I will dig more on the subject and once again, your method works just fine!! Thanks

Comment: Give it a go, start by creating your table then record a macro to clear then set the filter. Copy the data from the table and paste it into the destination sheet. Then when you look at it there will be some cleaning up and reference changes to make but the code will be very close to what you need. If you have difficulties comment back and we will sort it out.

Comment: OK, I will let you know. Thanks